# Global Resources In javascript file

Tags: javascript, culture, app-globalresources

To implement calture I am displaying error message using javascript global resources lang file but I dont get resource message in javascript file as in HTML I got it using following syntax:

Comment: Question is not complete. where is the "syntax...." ?

Comment: @SandeepGB It got hidden because SO thought it was HTML and it wasn't in a code block. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
 var validationText = '<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","ConfirmRemove") %>';
```